# stacking 2D matrix using Python

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, reshape

I have a script that reshapes a 1024x1024 matrix into 32x32 matrices. Here it is the code:

```
import numpy as np


filename = r'bb1e03'                    
background = r'bb1e03_background'               

size = 1024
resize = 32

n = np.arange(size)
T0 = np.loadtxt(filename, unpack=False)
bg = np.loadtxt(background, unpack=False)

T = T0-bg                                               

for s in n: # s here is the row number
    B = np.reshape(T[s], (resize, resize))
    B_rev = B[...,::-1]                                                                 
    name = str(filename) + '_column_'+ str.zfill(str(s), 4)   
    np.savetxt(name+'.txt', B_rev)
```

Now I need all 32x32 matrices stacked so that in the end I have a 32x32x1024 matrix. Could you please tell me how I can do that? I have found that np.dstack would do the job but I have no idea how to include it in the script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `np.dstack` needs a tuple of all of the matrices to stack you are going to have to store them separately as you go along anyway.

A simple solution to your problem would be to put the reshaped matrices in place in the stacked structure as you generate them.

```
stacked = np.empty((32, 32, 1024))
for s in xrange(1024):
    B = T[s].reshape((32, 32))
    B_rev = B[..., ::-1]
    stacked[...,s] = B_rev
```

You could also do this in one step with the one liner

```
stacked = T.reshape((1024,32,32)).transpose((1,2,0))[:,::-1]
```

This method should be preferred as with some brief benchmarking I've found it to be **much** (1000x) faster than the plain python loop.

Comment: I've added another way of reshaping the matrix with a oneliner.

Comment: The second option works well. First option complains that "i' is not defined.

Comment: Ahh yea there was a typo there I'm afraid which I've now changed. The second method should be preferred anyway as it is much (1000x) faster.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask. And the conversion back to 32x32 matrices how can it be done? I need them because each 32x32 matrix represents an image that I have to further process.

Comment: You can access each of the individual matrices as ``stacked[...,i]``

Comment: In which case it may be better to keep the shape of the stack of matrices shaped as a (1024x32x32) array. In which case the transformation would be ``stacked = T.reshape((1024, 32, 32))[...,::-1]`` and each matrix can be got as ``stacked[i]``

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner in Python so I have some problems in understanding you. So I should use this stacked = T.reshape((1024, 32, 32))[...,::-1] to stack the matrices as I want and each image (32x32 matrix) can be processed using stacked[i] (where i takes values from 1 to 1024). Is this right?